# ProductHunt API Authentication using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, oauth

I'm trying to use the **ProductHunt API** using **jQuery**. To use the ProductHunt API, you need to authenticate before you can access the data. I'm using the OAuth Authentication.

Here is the code that I have got.

```
// api key and secret 
key = "api key goes here"
secret = "api secret goes here"

var base_url = "https://api.producthunt.com/v1/"
var token_url = base_url +"oauth/token"    
var today_post_url = base_url + "posts"


function get_token(){
  var token = '';

  $.ajax({
    url: token_url,
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    header: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    data: {
        "client_id": key,
        "client_secret": secret,
        "grant_type": 'client_credentials'
      },
    success: (function(res) {            
        token = res.access_token;
    })
  });

    return (token);
}

function get_todays_posts() {
    token = get_token();
    console.log(token);        

    $.ajax({
      url: today_post_url,
      header: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
      },
      success: (function(res){
        return res;
      })
    })
}
```

But when I run `get_todays_post()`, I get a error message saying **GET https://api.producthunt.com/v1/posts 401 (Unauthorized)**